# Error: "setFile(null,false) call failed" when using log4j

Tags: java, file, logging, log4j

I have added `log4j.properties` file in source folder of project but I am still getting a log4j:error.

Here is my Log4j.properties file:

```
    .rootCategory=DEBUG, R, O
    # Stdout
    log4j.appender.O=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.O=log44j.log
    # File
    log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.R.File=log4j.log

    # Control the maximum log file size
    log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB

    # Archive log files (one backup file here)
    log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

    log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.O.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

    log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
    log4j.appender.O.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n

    # Define the root logger with appender file
    logDir = ../logs
    log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

    # Define the file appender
    log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/${file.name}
    log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

    # Define the layout for file appender
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Here is the Java exception that I am getting:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at lib.Dashboard.Reports.<init>(Reports.java:34)
    at testcases.AmazonDashboard.TC_DB17.main(TC_DB17.java:54)
AmazonDashboardTC_DB17Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testcases.AmazonDashboard.TC_DB17.main(TC_DB17.java:131)
```

Please let me know, how to resolve this exception, as I have tried placing my properties file in root folder and now I have placed in source folder but in both cases I got the above exception.

Comment: log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/${file.name}
this is not in the final file, right? So what is the value here in log4j.properties that has been deployed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140168/log4jerror-setfilenull-false-call-failed

Answer (score 29):

I suspect that the variable `${file.name}` is not substituted correctly. As a result, the value of `log4j.appender.FILE.File` becomes `logs/`. As such, Java tries to create a log file named `logs/`, but probably it is an existing directory, so you get the exception.

As a quick remedy, change the `log4j.appender.FILE.File` setting to point to file by absolute path, for example `/tmp/mytest.log`. You should not get an exception.

After that you can proceed to debugging why `${file.name}` is not replaced correctly in your runtime environment.

Comment: This is definitely useful in situations where the application has more than one log file

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem. Here is the solution that worked for me: simply put your properties file path in the cmd line this way :

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=<FILE_PATH>  (ex: log4j.properties)
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

i just add write permission to "logs" folder and it works for me

[image: add write permission]

Answer (score 2):

this error is coming because of appender file location you have provided is not reachable with current user access.

**Quick Solution**, change the log4j.appender.FILE.File setting to point to file using absolute path which location is reachable to the current user you have logged in, for example **/tmp/myapp.log**. Now You should not get an error.

Answer (score 1):

if it is window7(like mine), without administrative rights cannot write a file at C: drive

just give another folder in log4j.properties file

> Set the name of the file

log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:\server\log.out you can see with notepad++

Answer (score 1):

This is your config :

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/${file.name}
```

And this error happened :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs (Access is denied)
```

So it seems that the variable `file.name` is not set, and java tries to write to the directory `logs`.

---

You can **force** the value of your variable `${file.name}` calling maven with this option **-D** :

```
mvn clean test -Dfile.name=logfile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the error -
'log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs (Access is denied)'

It seems there's a log file named as 'logs' to which access is denied i.e it is not having sufficient permissions to write logs. Try by giving write permissions to the 'logs' log file. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please changes your log file location to another drive. it will work.

this happen's the permission of creating log file.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this isue I changed all values in log4j.properties file with directory ${kafka.logs.dir} to my own directory. For example D:/temp/...

Answer (score -4):

Try executing your command with sudo(Super User), this worked for me :) 
Run : $ sudo your_command 
After than enter the super user password. Thats All..

Comment: sometimes you cannot have such previlage on a shared system