# log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4net

Iam facing some strange error as below

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \debug.log (Access is denied)
```

**src/main/dev/environment/dev/config.properties**

```
logging.folder=D:/logs
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="append" value="false"/>
      <param name="file" value="${logging.folder}/debug.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
```

**maven.xml (not complete)**

```
<filters>
            <filter>src/main/environment/dev/config.properties</filter>
        </filters>
```

when iam directly using  `<param name="file" value="D:/logs/debug.log"/>` , its working fine, BUT when am using `<param name="file" value="${logging.folder}/debug.log"/>` iam getting above exception..

Iam pretty sure values from property file able to read, since one of my java file able to read values from this property file only.. then why can't this log4j.xml file able to read?

**please suggest me what went wrong?**

Comment: It really looks like the `config.properties` isn't getting read *before* the XML attribute is getting interpreted. I also note that your paths don't match, and you haven't specified the environment in which you're getting the error (is it a configuration where `dev` isn't enabled?).

Comment: @chrylis profile 'dev' is by-default enabled.. so can you tell me whats the solution for my issue pls?  and when iam directly using <param name="file" value="D:/logs/debug.log"/> , its working fine for me..

Comment: user3128668 - did you find answer to the above?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Chandra's answer, I experienced the same exception in Eclipse on Windows 7:

```
C:/myfile.log                     // access denied...
```

But it worked OK when I created a folder with permissions to my userid:

```
 C:/myLogs/myfile.log             // it wasn't necessary to create the file
```

I also noticed that the path must be specified with forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Use forward slash ('/') instead of back slash ('\')  where ever you are defining this path ${logging.folder}. Thats what error i see up there:

you are using back  slash here:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: \debug.log (Access is denied)

so your path should be something like:
logging.folder = D:/logs/

Answer (score 0):

For logging I use properties file and I use the following config for this same problem. As I use **tomcat server**, I use `${catalina.base}` to get the tomcat base directory. 
`log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.base}/logs/debug.log`

For your xml config the syntex might be like the following

```
<param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/debug.log"/>
```

If you are using **Tomcat** then hopefully It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is nothing related to slashes people.
This line of error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: \debug.log (Access is denied)

is telling us that it is trying to create debug.log file in the root(\ represents root)
and obviously it won't have access so access denied.

In my case, I solved this by adding VM arguments before starting the server. That's it.

### Example : (In my case I'm using `Wildfly`, change the path to your server location)

"`-Dlogging.folder=C:\Program Files\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\log`"