# log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, file, logging, log4j, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting the below error while compiling the application

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.java.io.FileNotFoundException:\gel\ms\ex\ms.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Below is my log4j config file:

```
#root log level
log4j.rootCategory=debug, R
log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.ibatis=DEBUG

# First type of log, output to file
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=/gel/ms/ex/ms.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%40c] %5p - %m%n
```

And my project folder hierachy

MS(Project Name)

1. Java Resource
2. WebContext

   2.a -META-INF

   2.b -WEB-INF

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682130/error-setfilenull-false-call-failed-when-using-log4j

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140168/log4jerror-setfilenull-false-call-failed/30486368#30486368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick solution, set the absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

Above error giving you a hint that the appender file is not reachable/readable with current user access.

in brief we can say that- without administrative rights, no one cannot write a file at C: drive

As a quick remedy, change the log4j.appender.FILE.File setting to point to file by absolute path, for example /tmp/test.log. 
Now You should not get an exception.

Comment: Thanks for including quick remedy including actual example