# log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.

Tags: log4j

My spring version is 4.2.5, (org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener) has been Abandoned.
Does Spring4.x has to use Log4j2.xml?

Here is my code.
I don't know where's went wrong?

**log4j.xml**

```
 /src/main/resources/log4j.xml
```

**web.xml**

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>webapp.root</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.WebAppRootListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<appender name="MANAGER-APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${webapp.root}/resources/logs/manager.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-5p] [%d{yyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %c{2}] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

**log file**

```
    ERR [err] log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
    ERR [err] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /resources/logs/manager.log (No such file or directory)
    ERR [err]   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    ERR [err]   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ERR [err]   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    ERR [err]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ERR [err]   at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    ERR [err]   at [internal classes]
    ERR [err]   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:302)
    ERR [err]   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    ERR [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2420)
    ERR [err]   at [internal classes]
    ERR [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$000(WebContainer.java:104)
    ERR [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$2.run(WebContainer.java:870)
    ERR [err]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    ERR [err]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    ERR [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    ERR [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ERR [err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    ERR [err] log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [MANAGER-APPENDER].
```

Thanks for taking the time to look and any help is awesome.

Comment: Maybe check this url > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597348/log4jerror-setfilenull-true-call-failed-java-io-filenotfoundexception?rq=1