# log4j-system can not find the path specified

Tags: java, logging

I am having log4j error and it's showing that the system can not find the path specified.

Here is the stack trace

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\conf\ErrorLog.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:272)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:156)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:151)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:247)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:123)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:87)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:645)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:603)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:500)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:406)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:432)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:460)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:113)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:85)
        at com.paymentech.orbital.sdk.configurator.Configurator.load(Configurator.java:369)
        at com.paymentech.orbital.sdk.configurator.Configurator.getInstance(Configurator.java:72)
        at com.teamexpress.ptech.Paymentech.<clinit>(Paymentech.java:57)
        at com.teamexpress.template.VariablesUtil.setStandardRequestVariables(VariablesUtil.java:195)
        at com.teamexpress.template.TemplateProcessor.<init>(TemplateProcessor.java:179)
        at com.teamexpress.template.TemplateProcessor.<init>(TemplateProcessor.java:86)
        at com.teamexpress.template.TemplateRedirector.forwardToTemplate(TemplateRedirector.java:321)
        at com.teamexpress.template.TemplateRedirector.doFilter(TemplateRedirector.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.teamexpress.servlet.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16780072/2551236

Comment: Can you post your configuration? Also, does that folder and file exist?

Comment: use forward slash ('/') instead of back slash ('\') while defining path

Answer (score 2):

Try to `./conf/ErrorLog.log` for your **log4j.properties** file

Answer (score 0):

The current directory is undetermined. It's 'C:\Windows\System32\' in my case.
I use

`<param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/my-audit.log" />`
etc.