# log4j error when using jboss variables

Tags: java, log4j

I'm trying to use log4j logging and trying to use `${jboss.server.log.dir}` in my properties file is giving me an error:

> log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: \server.log (Access is denied)

Basically, the line I'm using is:

`log4j.appender.myappender.File = ${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log`

Important points:

**1)** I can use the full path and it *will* work, so I imagine it's not permissions (as it's on my C drive)

**2)** I can use `${user.home}` and it will take the correct value and work as intended (albeit not the location I want to log to, but more of a test to see am I using the variables correctly)

**3)** If I use `\\` (i.e. `${jboss.server.log.dir}\\server.log`), I get the same error. If I use `//`, I get *The specified path is invalid*. If I use `\`, nothing happens - no error, nothing logged. I use `/` with `${user.home}` and that works ok. Note that this is on Windows only.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682130/error-setfilenull-false-call-failed-when-using-log4j), amongst many others, but it seems that any of the solutions aren't working.

One last point: upon bootup, I can see the path referenced by `${jboss.server.log.dir}` is `C:\path\to\somewhere` whereas I need to put in `C:\\path\\to\\somewhere` when hardcoding within the properties file, if that makes any difference.

So my question is: how can I use `${jboss.server.log.dir}` in place of hardcoding the full path (which I can't do)?

Comment: If you use "\", nothing happens. Is there something to log?

Comment: @LanceToth yes.

Answer (score 0):

Support for environment variable expansion is added in log4j 2, currently at version 2.10. Is it possible you are using an earlier version of log4j?